# CKEditor integration with Wiris PHP plugin: open_basedir restriction

Tags: php, ckeditor, wiris

As per Wiris guide.

1. Give execution rights to the web server user on the PHP files contained at to ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration.
   → My settings: Folder "integration": `755`. All files inside this folder: `754`
2. Give write permissions to ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/cache and to ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/formulas directories to the web server user. Those folders will be used to store formula MathML codes and temporal images.
   → My settings for these folder: `775`

However, I get following warnings while trying to open Wiris "Math Popup", and doesn't open properly.

> Warning: is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect.    File(/home/my_user_name/public_html/ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/../../../../../../../../lib/moodlelib.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/my_user_name:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/my_user_name/public_html/ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/bootstrap.php on line 39

> Warning: is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/my_user_name/public_html/ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/../../../../../../lib/moodlelib.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/my_user_name:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/my_user_name/public_html/ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/bootstrap.php on line 39

Are my permissions correct? Do these warnings relate to file/folder permissions? I am using [www.serversfree.com](http://www.serversfree.com) webhosting to test this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's an issue in your installation. Please check the plugin test page: 
`<url>/ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/test.php`. There shouldn't be any errors there. Please review the installation instructions at http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/ckeditor.

Comment: Test page shows all OK except "Creating a random image" that results in ERROR. The installation guide doesn't say much about what needs be fixed or changed in INI file.

Comment: Please check your server error log as you run the test.php page again and post or send us any errors you see. You should have either `allow_url_fopen=On`or CURL extension enabled. If you have `allow_url_fopen=Off` check that there are no CURL related functions in your disable_functions in php.ini. Does the file "392b9defa8cb3eaf2f8fec0cf3993738.png" exist in your cache directory (ckeditor_wiris/cache)?

Comment: Thanks a lot WIRIS team. For time being I decided to use the ckeditor on your demo page, solves my purpose.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't hesitate getting back to us at support@wiris.com anytime.

Comment: test .php giving me internal server error what can i do ? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your permissions are correct. Those warnings are related to an extra check in the `/integration/bootstrap.php` file, it checks a directory several levels above your working directory and you're not allowed to do so due to an open_basedir restriction in your server. This issue will be fixed in our next plugin release. To supress the warning simply comment the whole `bootstrap.php` file or add a `return true;` right after `<?php`.

Edit: This issue is currently fixed in our latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Please give permission to 777 to folder named **cache** and **formulas**

inside path

ckeditor4/plugins/ckeditor_wiris

Comment: Using permission `777` should be the last resort since it makes your system open for intruders. It's recommended to add the respective user to the proper group.